# What shall we do with closed, up-voted questions, which have no answers?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, site-cleanup

During my ventures in cleaning, I came across another phenomenon of quasi-dead questions, that won't get cleaned up, but (most) are essentially noise. There are a few ([currently 227](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3A1+isanswered%3A0+score%3A1..+duplicate%3A0)) questions which have a positive score, but are closed (excluding duplicates) and no-one "answered" them before they were. And by that I mean that they are unanswered by SE definitions (they might have no-scoring answers).

In my opinion, they are noise. There is little to nothing be taken from them in general. I did not go though them, but a few I saw were abandoned. About half of these questions ([currently 137](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3A1+isanswered%3A0+score%3A1..+duplicate%3A0+lastactive%3A..6m)) have not been active within the last six months.
In general they might be in not too good shape, often scoring lower than two (cut-off after the first page of search results). But with these questions, there is some reputation on the line, typically lower than 10, for the OP.

There are a few options:

1. the radical approach: **delete**
2. the semi-radical approach: **delete**, after a thorough review, salvaging all information in the comments section, might include discussion in dedicated chat room
3. the almost not radical approach: **delete**, after salvage and try to contact OP to rescue the question, then **reopen**
4. the communism approach: **disown**, turn the contents around to fit our site and make it *community wiki*, **reopen**, and possibly answer
5. the minimalism approach: clean up tags and format, let it be
6. something else

#### How should we proceed with these questions? Are there criteria I have forgotten?

On a side note: Please also exercise your right to down-vote. Questions that do not fit well in our system will get cleaned up after a while when they have a negative score. In some frantic cases it let's us also see whether a question is controversial or not.

Comment: Disown, reopen, close, delete, dismember and incapacitate. O.O

Comment: I think Roomba takes care of most of these eventually, but there are always questions that are prohibited from being Roomba'd by a single upvote or comment. That's when peeps on SO usually either delete comments or downvote so the question qualifies for Roomba or vote to delete themselves.

Comment: @M.A.R. Yes, the general trouble I have is, that when I vote to delete, I do delete. I do down-vote most of them though. But sometimes one is not enough.

Comment: Then I guess there is no course of action except posting a link in chat, if you're unhappy with mod-deleting them yourself

Comment: Keep the ones that are receiving traffic.

Comment: @Melanie Traffic is not really a criterion for quality, and even if the bring traffic they are not helpful since they have no answer.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly: **Not all of them have to be deleted.** As far as possible we should aim to salvage questions. However, for those that are truly useless, I support

> #### the semi-radical approach: delete, after a thorough review, salvaging all information in the comments section, might include discussion in dedicated chat room

As I mentioned in [an earlier comment](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3633/how-should-we-deal-with-bad-questions-that-attracted-not-too-helpful-answers#comment5325_3633) I'm worried about taking route (1), i.e. delete without oversight. It is not that I do not trust the moderators to make decisions in the best interests of the site. (After all, I *am* one too...) I just do not believe that this is a healthy approach to take. We have all the powers to be [benevolent dictators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benevolent_dictatorship) but that does not mean that we have to sacrifice **transparency** and **accountability**. This is especially important with a *site cleanup*, which is something the entire community should be participants in. (Compare to, for example, detecting sockpuppetry and suspending users, which is a *moderator task* and does not necessarily need to be shared with the public.)

That means that every action we take should be a consensus decision, and every action should be documented somewhere. That raises a couple of questions.

1. What counts as "consensus"? My opinion is that **two mods** should be enough. You may disagree. Feel free to raise any objections in the comment section.
2. What is the best place to document this? A meta thread would be possible, but is too crowded and too painful to monitor consistently. A **chat room** would work best.

---

I disagree with trying to contact OPs, especially when they have been inactive for a long time. The Stack Exchange [Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal) are very clear on this (Section 3):

> You agree that all Subscriber Content that You contribute to the Network is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Exchange [...]

OPs therefore no longer have any rights over their questions. We usually do not remind people of this, simply because of *courtesy*: we would like to respect people's wishes as to how their questions will be handled. However, there is a limit to this, and if we waste time trying to contact long-gone OPs it will significantly slow down our progress.

Comment: It only takes three users to dovn-vote any closed score 2 question (the majority) to negative, and therefore making it eligible for the deletion scripts, there would be not really documentation about it. I therefore would say that if any two users agree, it should be okay.//  Any closed, unanswered question with score >2 will be removed after one year, I would argue that in some cases we should just accelerate the process, or turn it into a "good" question if possible (It probably isn't). However, I think a chat room works fine for discussing such cases.