# The Great Retagging Event -- Episode 2: Spring Cleaning

Tags: discussion, retagging, chat-event

Finally, TRE is back, and we've got stuff to do.

This episode will feature the following tags:

- [reaction](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reaction) questions: As we see fit, we will retag ones that are worth it, delete ones that deserve it, and edit ones that need it. (see [Should we delete and blacklist [reaction]?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3601/4945)).

  - UPDATE: Even though [reaction](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reaction) has now been [burninated](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/3601/8), we still have a list of the questions that it had been applied to, and plan to go through them and (re)tag/edit/delete as apppropriate.
- [homework](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) questions will get the same treatment. (see [Do we really need [homework]? [Part 3]](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3640/4945))

Once we're reasonably done with those,

- **PLANNED** (Continue) flagging hint-ish answers as NAA (see [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3661/are-answers-that-only-contain-hints-to-be-considered-answers-or-not))
- **PLANNED** Moderate questions with buzzword-y titles (most recent related meta post [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3389/i-have-a-doubt-about-doubt-in-doubt-titles); includes links to other buzzword posts).

Additional cleanup activities are up for discussion:

- [What shall we do with closed, up-voted questions, which have no answers?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3654/what-shall-we-do-with-closed-up-voted-questions-which-have-no-answers)
- [How should we deal with bad questions that attracted not too helpful answers?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3633/how-should-we-deal-with-bad-questions-that-attracted-not-too-helpful-answers)
- A list of additional tags for potential cleanup is being curated in the "Future Tag Actions" Project of the Chem.SE Cleanup GitHub organization (see below)

### Useful links

- Here's the link to the [Spring Cleaning](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55978/spring-cleaning) chat.
- We also have a [Github organization thingy](https://github.com/ChemSECleanup). Ping any of the Spring Cleaning chat [room owners](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/55978/spring-cleaning#room-ownercards) with your Github username for an invite to the organization.
- If you wish, you can [announce your availability](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lZnQWSWpvYtBtzrXTdzWQjO-NL5rkZMlxOtkMiat32o/edit?usp=sharing) in the linked Google sheet so we would readjust the time for the other TREs if necessary.
- [Spring Cleaning FAQ](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3673/introducing-spring-cleaning?rq=1)

[image]

Comment: Can we get a summary of what you did during the first chat session?

Comment: Mart, you mean the event stats? I was kinda too lazy to do them. Ask Brian.

Comment: well, an answer with a short description, like *deleted many closed questions* and a linkt to the transcript would suffice I think

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Done.

Answer (score 2):

A [reaction](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reaction) cleanup event took place on 8 Apr 2017, from approximately 3:30 to 6:00 UDT.  Participants in the main event included (listed in alphabetical order; if I missed anybody, please edit yourself in!):

- hBy2Py
- M.A.R.
- Mithoron
- orthocresol

Loong dropped in to assist with some extra mod actions, and Melanie Shebel was active prior to the "official" event.  Other, such as paracetamol (formerly paracresol), have continued the cleanup effort after the event. During the main event itself, approximately 75 questions were cleaned up; in total, approximately 105 of the 705 original questions have been addressed.

The chat activity for the event was spread across two rooms; bookmarked conversations covering the chat transcripts for these rooms are:

- [Spring Cleaning](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55978/conversation/reaction-cleanup-event-8-apr-2017)
- [Spring Cleaning Scratch](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56752/conversation/reaction-cleanup-event-8-apr-2017)

---

The [burnination and blacklist](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3601/should-we-delete-and-blacklist-reaction) of [reaction](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reaction) has been completed, but a list of the questions that *used to be* tagged and that still need review is located in [this Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T9s2yFfLbXcqFrIMwSZLEerUYS3g1UnQAn9dNWhJqJA/edit#gid=0). Anyone who wishes to help is welcome to check and clean up these questions. Please report any cleanup activity to the [Spring Cleaning chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55978/spring-cleaning).  Don't deal with more than four or five at once, though, to avoid flooding the front page of the site with these old questions.  Once you've cleaned one of these up (by whatever means, even if that's "taking no action"), please **delete the corresponding row** from the Google sheet to indicate as such.

Comment: UPDATE: The sheet linked to in the second part of this answer still says "533 remaining"
 but actually [tag:reaction] is no longer being used. Hooray!

Comment: @GaurangTandon Actually, 533 do still remain. [reaction] was blacklisted before we'd finished its cleanup. We started the blacklist process before we decided to attempt cleanup, and ran out of time, per the last section of my after-action report answer, here.

Comment: "533 do still remain" oh well that's disturbing :(

Comment: @GaurangTandon Well, there were 900-some when the sheet was created, so progress *is* slowly being made!